# Event Receiver ItemAdded not firing when uploading file via CopyIntoItems method of Copy.asmx web service

Tags: web-services, event-receivers

When I manually copy and paste the file into the library, the event receiver ItemAdded runs normally.

But when the file is uploaded via web service it does not run.

Any ideas?

My code:

```
public string UploadFilePortal(string pathArquivo)
    {
        string docLibrary = "http://site/web/financeiro/";
        string libraryUrl = "ComprovantesPagamento";
        string retorno = String.Empty;
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(pathArquivo);


        Utils.LogTextoCpvtes("Uploading file... " + pathArquivo +
                        DateTime.Now.ToString());


        WSCopy.Copy wsCopy = new WSCopy.Copy();

        wsCopy.Url = docLibrary + "_vti_bin/copy.asmx";
        wsCopy.Credentials = GetUserPortal();

        byte[] binaryFile = File.ReadAllBytes(pathArquivo);

        string pasta = @"/";


        // Valor Pagamento:
        WSCopy.FieldInformation fieldValor = new
                                        WSCopy.FieldInformation();
        fieldValor.DisplayName = "ValorPagamento";
        fieldValor.InternalName = "ValorPagamento";
        fieldValor.Type = WSCopy.FieldType.Currency;
        fieldValor.Value = "0";

        // Negocio:
        WSCopy.FieldInformation fieldNegocio = new
                                        WSCopy.FieldInformation();
        fieldNegocio.DisplayName = "Negocio";
        fieldNegocio.InternalName = "Negocio";
        fieldNegocio.Type = WSCopy.FieldType.Choice;
        fieldNegocio.Value = "OR";

        // IDDocRastreabilidade:
        WSCopy.FieldInformation fieldIdDocRastr = new
                                        WSCopy.FieldInformation();
        fieldIdDocRastr.DisplayName = "IDDocRastreabilidade";
        fieldIdDocRastr.InternalName = "IDDocRastreabilidade";
        fieldIdDocRastr.Type = WSCopy.FieldType.Number;
        fieldIdDocRastr.Value = "0";


        //WSCopy.FieldInformation[] fields = { fieldTitle };

        WSCopy.FieldInformation[] fields = { fieldValor, fieldNegocio, fieldIdDocRastr };

        string destiny = docLibrary +
                            libraryUrl +
                            @"/" +
                            fileName;

        string otherDestiny = fileName;

        string[] destinationUrl = { destiny };

        WSCopy.CopyResult resultTest = new WSCopy.CopyResult();
        WSCopy.CopyResult[] result = { resultTest };

        try
        {
            wsCopy.CopyIntoItems(otherDestiny, destinationUrl,
                                    fields, binaryFile, out result);

            if (result[0].ErrorCode != WSCopy.CopyErrorCode.Success)
            {
                //exception:
                throw new ImpossibleUploadFilePortalException(
                            "Not possible upload file: " +
                                result[0].ErrorCode.ToString() + " - " +
                                result[0].ErrorMessage);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw exc;
        }

        return retorno;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your event receiver code?

Comment: code posted @RobertLindgren

Comment: Sorry, I was more interested in the ItemAdded code